# Django Rest Framework serializers as forms and nested relationships

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use the django rest framework to generate html forms for model creation. Suppose I have a serializer that belongs to a model with a `ManyToMany` relation.

```
class SerializerExample(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mtm = ManyToManySerializer(many=True)
```

I then, in a django rest view,

```
class AddModelView(StandardView):
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    template_name = 'details.html'

    def get(self, request):
        model = Model.objects.get.all()
        serializer = ModelSerializer(model)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'model': model})
```

And then suppose details.html looks like:

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<html><body>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% render_form serializer %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>

    </body></html>
```

`Lists are not currently supported in HTML input.` instead of a multiselect or the abiliity to add new instances. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. This is work in progress.
Either use JSON with nested serializers or don't use nested serializers if you need HTML Forms.

Comment: is there json form creation for the serializer that creates a form in json following that w3c standard?

Comment: I've used options in the past to get an automatic form out of the json part. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/

Comment: I actually ended up writing my own. Works really well with my react front end. will post on github soon.

Comment: Interesting, let us know about it.